# returns NaN for the total price but total quantity works fine

Tags: javascript

I have this cart page and I'm returning the total quantity and total price of items in cart. it works for returning the total quantity but not total price it says NaN and i cant figure out why. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

function Total() {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);

  const getTotal = () => {
    let totalQuantity = 0;
    let totalPrice = 0;
    cart.forEach((item) => {
      totalQuantity += item.quantity;
      totalPrice += item.price * item.quantity;
    });
    return { totalPrice, totalQuantity };
  };

  return (
    <div className="total">
      <h2 className="order__summary">ORDER SUMMARY</h2>
      <div>
        <p className="total__p">
          total items in cart is {getTotal().totalQuantity} -{" "}
          <strong> ${(getTotal().totalPrice)}</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Total;
```

```
const getTotal = () => {
    let totalQuantity = 0;
    let totalPrice = 0;
    cart.forEach((item) => {
      totalQuantity += item.quantity;
      totalPrice += item.price * item.quantity;
    });
    return { totalPrice, totalQuantity };
  };
```

i've tried declaring total price outside the getTotal function and i still get NaN

Comment: You got to debug and figure it out since we do not have access to the data. `console.log(totalPrice, item.price, item.quantity, item.price * item.quantity);` My guess is price is not what you think it is.

Comment: Nitpick: You should store the result of getTotal in a variable so you are not calculating it twice to get the totals in two places.

Comment: ahh, i figured it out i was storing price key in the array object as a string. Thanks for your help, much appreciated! :)